# Nrwl DataPersistence Fetch Function doesn't fire run function with AngularFiresotre stateChange() function

Tags: angular, angularfire2, nrwl

I need to paginate through my data in Firestore,

in my Effect I'm using `fetch` operator by DataPersistence Class ([Nx DataPersistence](https://nx.dev/latest/angular/guides/misc-data-persistence)),

after the first "fetch" the `run` function doesn't fire on subsequent actions

```
query$ = createEffect((): any =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(Actions.query),
      logOperator('Effect 1'),
      fetch({
        run: (action): Observable<MyData> => {
          return this.backEndService.query(action.batchNumber, action.batchSize).pipe(
            logOperator('Effect 2'),
            map(
              (doc: { type: 'added' | 'removed' | 'modified'; payload: MyData}): Action => {
                switch (doc.type) {
                  case 'added': {
                    return Actions.added({ data: doc.payload });
                  }
                  case 'removed': {
                    return Actions.removed({ data: doc.payload });
                  }
                  case 'modified': {
                    return Actions.modified({ data: doc.payload });
                  }
                  default: {
                    return Actions.queryFailure({
                      error: {
                        payload: doc,
                        message: 'UNKNOWN_ACTION',
                      },
                    });
                  }
                }
              }
            )
          );
        },
        onError: (action, error): any => {
          return Actions.queryFailure({ error: { error, action } });
        },
      })
    )
  );
```

if I remove the `fetch` Operator and use `switchMap` instead everything work just fine

```
query$ = createEffect((): any =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
          ofType(Actions.query),
          logOperator('Effect 1'),
          switchMap(
            (action): Observable<Action> => {
              return this.backEndService.query(action.batchNumber, action.batchSize).pipe(
                 logOperator('Effect 2'),
                map(
                  (doc: { type: 'added' | 'removed' | 'modified'; payload: MyData}): Action => {
                    switch (doc.type) {
                      case 'added': {
                        return Actions.added({ data: doc.payload });
                      }
                      case 'removed': {
                        return Actions.removed({ data: doc.payload });
                      }
                      case 'modified': {
                        return Actions.modified({ data: doc.payload });
                      }
                      default: {
                        return Actions.queryFailure({
                          error: {
                            payload: doc,
                            message: 'UNKNOWN_ACTION',
                          },
                        });
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ),
                catchError((error) =>
                  of(
                    Actions.queryFailure({
                      error: {
                        payload: error,
                        message: 'QUERY ERROR',
                      },
                    })
                  )
                )
              );
            }
          )
        )
      );
```

in both cases the `query` function of the `backEndService` is the following one

```
  public query(
    batchNumber = 1,
    batchSize = 40
  ): Observable<{
    type: 'added' | 'removed' | 'modified';
    payload: MyData;
  }> {
    return this.firestore
      .collection<MyData>(
        COLLECTION_ID,
        (ref: CollectionReference): Query =>
          ref
            .where('available', '==', true)
            .where('active', '==', true)
            .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
            .limit(batchSize * batchNumber)
      )
      .stateChanges()
      .pipe(
        logOperator('Service'),
        map(
          (
            documentsChangeAction: DocumentChangeAction<Order>[]
          ): Observable<{
            type: 'added' | 'removed' | 'modified';
            payload: MyData;
          }> => {
            return from(documentsChangeAction).pipe(
              map((doc: DocumentChangeAction<MyData>): {
                type: 'added' | 'removed' | 'modified';
                payload: MyData;
              } => {
                return {
                  type: doc.type,
                  payload: {
                    ...doc.payload.doc.data(),
                    id: doc.payload.doc.id,
                  },
                };
              })
            );
          }
        ),
        concatAll()
      );
  }
```

Comment: *fatch*? what is that?

Comment: https://nx.dev/latest/angular/guides/misc-data-persistence

The fetch operator provides consistency when fetching data. If there are multiple requests scheduled for the same action, it will only run the last one.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problema with my set of effects. Try adding the id prop as the second example shows [DataPersistence](https://nx.dev/l/a/guides/misc-data-persistence#data-fetching).

It should be something like

```
fetch({
   id: (action) => {
     return action.id
   },
   run: (action) = {
    ...
   }
```